# Why my program returns characters i didn't input? (Pure C)

Tags: c, arrays, char

My program: Something is wrong

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
//Функция для проверки соответствия символов.
int ifSignsCorrect(char theChar) {
    if ((theChar >= 'A' && theChar <= 'Z') || (theChar >= 'a' && theChar <= 'z') || theChar == '.' || theChar == ' ' || theChar == '*') return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    char string[256];
    int i = 0;
    //Заполняем массив
    for (i = 0; i < 256; i++) {


        scanf("%c\n", &string[i]);
        if (string[i] == '*') break;
        printf("%с\n", string[i]);
        if (ifSignsCorrect(string[i]) != 1) {
            printf("You used wrong characer, formating disc C (Just joking)\n");
            return;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: When `i == 0`, what will return this expression  `string[i - 1] != '*'`?

Comment: *Something is wrong*.... what, exactly, is wrong, once you've corrected the cited mistakes? (NOTE: `scanf` will return after the user presses ENTER ('\n') - do you know what happens in your program when ENTER is reached?)

Comment: Change `if (string[i - 1] == '*' && i != 0)` as `if (i != 0 && string[i - 1] == '*')`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answers have been edited into the question, and it can't be rolled back easily due to subsequent formatting edits , so this is unlikely to be useful to anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things I want to mention:

**First:**

You are trying to access invalid pieces of memory with this code:

> ```
> int i = 0;
> while (string[i - 1] != '*') {
> ```

In the first iteration you will access `string[-1]`. You have to solve that first.

**Second:**

You are defining an array of pointers in this line:

```
char *string[256];
```

use an array of characters `char string[256];` instead.

**Third:**

You could just print like this:

```
printf("You used wrong characer, formating disc C (Just joking)\n");
```

Unless you want to define variable that will indicate this error_message, that could be cleaner some times, specially is you are going to reuse it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks i will fix problems.

Answer (score 1):

You used an array of pointers instead of array of characters here:

```
 char *string[256];
```

You are also accessing the array out of bounds here:

```
while (string[i - 1] != '*') {    // here i == -1
```

Also a if statement after the scanf() like this would be proper:

```
if( string[i] == '*' )
    break ;
```

EDIT:

Why does the program only print the character `?` ?
Because the character `c` in the line `printf("%с\n", string[i]);` is actually not an ascii `c`

Try copying it into a program that only supports ascii. I copied it into notepad++ and set the encoding to ascii and it turned to `?` :) . Must be a multilanguage support error as i see you have cyrillic enabled.

Comment: I deleted * but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Yes, i did it. But i still can't understand why it returns ё for every letter i type.